# NoModificationAllowedError in Hawtio

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix, hawtio

I deployed a camel route in Servicemix in my local machine with hawtio feature installed. Im able to view the diagram, source, osgi bundle, trace, debug in hawtio url

```
http://localhost:8181/hawtio/
```

with username and password smx/smx or karaf/karaf

But when i deploy the same route in a virtual machine running in another network and check in the hawtio, its showing NoModificationAllowedError on checking the camel contexts.

Can someone help me out from this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details, about versions used, and maybe some stacktrace / logs about this error.

Comment: Servicemix 5.4.0, Apache camel 2.14.1, hawtio 1.2.3. The local machine in which its working is windows 7, the virtual machine in which the same replica of servicemix is running is windows 8.

Comment: you got any log of that exception/error you can post? Also hawtio 1.2.3 is a bit old, you can try to upgrade also.

Comment: No exception/Error logged. But it shows only in Hawtio page on trying to access the routes.